# QGIS 2.2 is very slow while saving the edited layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.2

I am using QGIS 2.2 64 bit in windows 7 system. I have an issue while saving the layers after editing. Its taking more time to save my edits. Some times it's working fine but very often i am getting this issue and also the QGIS will be in  Not Responding stage at that time. I tried in different postgres database and different types of layers(polyline and polygons) but still having the same issue.

Is anyone having any idea to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is usually caused by a plugin. Try disabling installed plugins one by one and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting these layers from postgres/postgis connection using qgis db connection ?

how many polyline/polygons do each of these layers have aprox?

Are you saving these layers at your own local harddrive (no network drive)?

Please do save them localy.

you can also export postgres/postgis tables to shape using pgsql2shp

here's some info: http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/postgis/import_export.html

Comment: Yes, I am connecting the layers from postgres/postgis connection using qgis db connection.

It contains around 4000 polygons and also i have this issue with low volume of feature and high volume of features.

No, I am saving my edits in server thru network.